# Python for-loop does not write to file

Tags: python, for-loop, logging

I try to to execute following piece of code:

```
# Counter
    n = 1
    # now we write the updated stack into the new file
    logger.write_log("info", "Writing the new grocerylist without the removed values")
    for item in stack:
        logger.write_log("debug", "grocery_list.txt gets called with append-permissions")
        with open("grocery_list.txt", "a") as grocery_list:
            try:
                testcase = int(item[2])
                logger.write_log("debug", "Item was originally above the 10th place")
                grocery_list.write("g%s" % n + item[3:])
                logger.write_log("debug", item.replace("\n","") + "got added at the " + str(n) + "th place")
            except ValueError:
                grocery_list.write("g%s" % n + item[2:])
                logger.write_log("debug", item.replace("\n","") + "got added at the " + str(n) + "th place")
        n = n + 1
    grocery_list.close()
    logger.write_log("debug", "grocery_list.txt got closed")
```

Inside of this Code following function for writing logs gets called:

```
# Function which writes the provided logline into our logfile
def write_log(loglevel, logline):
if loglevel_config == loglevel or loglevel_config == "debug" or loglevel == "error":
    # We open the website_flask-log because that is also the log where internal flask errors are shown
    with open ("website.log", "a") as logfile:
        # We write the current time and the message we want into it
        logfile.write( str(datetime.now()) + " " + loglevel.upper() + ": " + logline + "\n")
        # We close the logfile
        logfile.close()
```

But when the code gets executed, the log does not get written.
The lines inside the for-loop are missing.

```
2022-10-09 21:57:15.483658 INFO: inform_stock.stock_add_item gets called
2022-10-09 21:57:15.587647 DEBUG: Itemplace is below the 10th place
2022-10-09 21:57:15.691526 INFO: inform_stock.stock_add_item got initialized
2022-10-09 21:57:15.795606 INFO: trying to send data to following endpoint: http://10.0.0.90:8001/add_item?item=Hallo
2022-10-09 21:57:15.915396 INFO: Writing the new grocerylist without the removed values
2022-10-09 21:57:16.019588 DEBUG: grocery_list.txt got closed
2022-10-09 21:57:16.123527 DEBUG: Calling of grocery_list.get_grocery_list-function
```

Following steps were already tried in order to solve the issue:

1. To keep the logfile inside of the logger.py open
2. To sleep 5 seconds between each entry
3. To sleep one second each time the write_log gets called
4. To flush after each time the write_log gets called

Maybe useful information:
This for-loop does work:

```
            for item in stack:
            if field in item[:3]:
                logger.write_log("info", "Following item matched the removal-criteria: " + item.replace("\n",""))
                stack.remove(item)
                logger.write_log("debug", "Item " + item.replace("\n", "") + " got removed")
                # if an item gets removed, that means we bought it
                # we inform our stock-db that the article is bought
                logger.write_log("info", "inform_stock.stock_add_item gets called")
                try:
                    # this is needed because our input-field and our item has a crazy format
                    # this try-/except is in order to see if we have a value that is over the 10th place on our list
                    try:
                        int(item[2])
                        logger.write_log("debug", "Itemplace is over the 10th place")
                        inform_stock.stock_add_item(item[3:].strip().capitalize())
                    except ValueError as e:
                        logger.write_log("debug", "Itemplace is below the 10th place")
                        inform_stock.stock_add_item(item[2:].strip().capitalize())
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.write_log("error", "Was not able to call inform_stock.py. Following error occured: " + str(e))
```

The stack(list) contains most times one and sometimes up to 10 values.

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of the code?

Comment: You don't need `logfile.close()` since `with` does that automatically. And `grocery_list.close()` isn't even inside the `with`, so the file has already been closed.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that `stack` is empty.

Comment: @Barmar You were right, through a bug earlier in the script, the list was empty. I did not think about an earlier error, thank you very much :D
Of course to all the others too.